# Google Play Services - Sending A Rematch Request

Tags: google-play-services

After a multiplayer game is over, is there any possibility of sending a rematch request to the same participants?

Note that this is not provided by the Google API, I am wondering if people have any ideas on implementing such a system.

Thanks,
Rajat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a solution to inviting all the same people from the previous game.. this works for the player that initiated that initiated the game:

When you get back the Intent from selecting the players.. just save it:

```
 // Handle the result of the "Select players UI" we launched when the user clicked the
// "Invite friends" button. We react by creating a room with those players.
private void handleSelectPlayersResult(int response, Intent data) {
    if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.w(TAG, "*** select players UI cancelled, " + response);
        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mGHInterface.onBackedOut();

            }
        });
       return;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Select players UI succeeded.");

    previousMatch = data;

    // get the invitee list ...(etc, etc)
```

Then, whatever way you want to activate the next bit of code works:

```
@Override
    public void sendOutRematch() {
        handleSelectPlayersResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, previousMatch);
    }
```

Now, for players that are invited to the room... need to look at the Room object for them, and get the invited player id's from that object.. and save that list of players so it can be used in the Room Creation process with something like this to grab the ids :

```
ArrayList<String> playerIDs;
        for (Participant p : room.getParticipants()) {
            playerIDs.add(p.getPlayer().getPlayerId());
        }
```

then use that list in your room creation process.

Comment: Good idea :) This should be useful. Thank you!